# Androguard output truncated

Tags: android, python, proguard, androguard

I installed androguard to help me analyze my own apps to verify that proguard is doing its job (like removing Log.* messages.)

It works well in general, but I have a problem with commands with long outputs.  Two examples are with AnalyzeAPK():

```
get_strings()
get_classes_names()
```

When I run these commands, I get a bunch of output relating to the support library, and it abruptly ends with an ellipsis before getting to the classes or strings that I created:

```
u'Landroid/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable;',
u'Landroid/support/v7/text/AllCapsTransformationMethod;',
...]
```

The same thing happens trying to dump the strings.

My question is - what do I have to do to get the full output of the commands?

Fedora 25 - Python 2.7.13 - ipython 5.0 - Androguard 3.0dev

Comment: Well I found a workaround for the string part - use `get_regex_strings("TESTSTRING")` to narrow down the output to the strings you are looking for.